# How to I get an extra field for a user profile when using EntityFieldQuery()

Tags: users, entities

I'm currently using something like this:

```
$users = new EntityFieldQuery();
        $users->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
        ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$result = $users->execute();
```

Which is great, but it returns a list of 1000 ids. How do I get an extra field with this, without loading 100 user profiles (which would be quite time consuming). So for example I need to get the profile field - `field_profile_company`

I tried user `user_load_multiple($result['user']);`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The result that comes from [`EntityFieldQuery::execute`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3Aexecute/7) contains an array of entity types, and within each of those is an array of the entities found in the query.

The caveat is that the entity ID is actually the *array key* of said array, so to use `user_load_multiple()` you would use syntax like this:

```
$users = user_load_multiple(array_keys($result['user']));
```

Comment: Thanks, Yea I realise, but it takes a lot of resources to user_load_multiple on over 1000 users. Is there a simpler way to just get a specific field with the original EntityFieldQuery::execute to save a query?

Comment: 'Fraid not, `EntityFieldQuery` only does a `JOIN` for tables that are included as part of the query condition and even then it won't select anything other than the entity type and entity ID. You *could* use [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7) and add a tag to the query so that you can manually decide which fields to include in the `SELECT` part of the statement. Have a look at [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1157006#comment-5465034) for more info